# Objective-C Loop for isEqualToString

Tags: objective-c, string, loops

In an if/else statement a globally declared property receives text in string format:

```
if ([[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-01"] || [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-02"] ||
    [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-03"] || [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-04"] ||
    [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-05"] || [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-06"] ||
    [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-07"] || [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-08"] ||
    [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-09"] || [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-10"] ||
    [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-11"] || [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-12"] ||
    [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-13"] || [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-14"] ||
    [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-15"] || [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-16"] ||
    [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-17"] || [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-18"] ||
    [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-19"] || [[_lengthLbl text] isEqualToString:@"00:-20"]) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self lessThan20SecondsPopUp];
    });
}
```

Is there a way to set up a loop so that I loop through these text values?

I set the value of the _lengthLbl earlier in the class like this:

```
- (IBAction)lengthSliderValueDidChange:(UISlider *)sender
    {
        NSInteger totalSeconds = [sender value] ;

        NSInteger minutes = totalSeconds / 60 ;
        NSInteger seconds = totalSeconds % 60 ;

        [_lengthLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld", (long)minutes, (long)seconds]];

    }
```

Comment: `_lengthLbl` is better represented by something else other than a string.  Convert it to minutes (integer) or something easier to manage.

Comment: It is difficult to convert it to seconds or minutes because it is a display for videos. One side is minutes, another is seconds. In such a case is conversion to a single integerValue possible?

Comment: So convert it to seconds.  Convert as soon as possible and only represent it within controls using `MM:SS`.  And BTW "minus 16 seconds" is "-00:16" and not "00:-16".

Comment: @trojanfoe: Is `totalSeconds` accessible inside of `lengthSliderValueDidChange`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to put all of the possible values in an `NSArray`. Then simply do:

```
if ([valuesArray containsObject:_lengthLbl.text]) {
}
```

Another option is to check the string like this:

```
if ([_lengthLbl.text hasPrefix:@"00:-"] && _lengthLbl.text.legnth == 6) {
    NSString *numPart = [_lengthLbl.txt substringFromIndex:4];
    int num = [numPart intValue];
    if (num >= 1 && num <= 20) {
        // good string value
    }
}
```

Having said this, you need to reevaluate what you are doing.

1. Why are you looking at a label instead of the data used to populate the label?
2. Why not check some numeric value representing the time?

It seems you have a `UISlider` outlet in your controller. Since I don't know the name lets call it `self.timeSlider`.

Now your code becomes:

```
NSInteger value = self.timeSlider.value;
if (value >= -20 && value <= -1) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self lessThan20SecondsPopUp];
    });
}
```

Comment: What and keep the values as strings?  Bad idea.

Comment: I added the IBAction where I capture the data for the UILabel.

Comment: OK, you have a slider with the data. Why not check the slider's value instead of parsing the label's text which is based on the slider's value?

Comment: @rmaddy How would I access `totalSeconds` inside of `lengthSliderValueDidChange`?

Comment: Do you mean where you have the `if` statement now? Just access the slider outlet and get its value.

Comment: I declared totalSeconds as a global variable. How would access the slider outlet to fetch its value?